# What are the best known methods for installing programs or scripts for current user only?

Tags: paths, pip

Looking for a good (easy, intuitive) way to deploy my Python scripts to users in our lab. Found that `pip install --user` installs the stuff into `~/.local/bin` - but this directory is not in PATH in typical Ubuntu setup. 
Directory `~/bin` is in PATH. So why pip won't install there? Even if there is some hidden parameter in pip config to specify per-user bin directory, I do not want to have users tweak their pip config. I'm thinking about turning `~/bin` into symlink that points to `~/.local/bin`, this is easy and can be done only once. Users do not have to tweak their PATH and pip is happy.

What do you think? Can this linking lead to any trouble?

Comment: What do you mean by "why `pip` won't install there"? The expected behavior of `pip install --user` in Ubuntu *is* to install into `~/.local/bin`, so if you don't want that, then don't use the `--user` option. The easiest way to let all users use the `--user` option and not have to tweak `$PATH` is to simply add `~/.local/bin` to `$PATH` in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Ah. So, /etc/environment is what I overlooked. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I wrote a more comprehensive answer. See if that helps you.

Comment: Perfect. So my setups were too old and do not have this fix yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the expected behavior of `pip install --user` in Ubuntu is to install into `~/.local/bin`, so if you don't want that, then you should not use the `--user` option.

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1588562, new user accounts created after the patch has landed will have `$HOME/.local/bin` added to `$PATH` by default. You can verify this by reading what is inside `/etc/skel/.profile`. I also have uploaded a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/edwinksl/dafc0594176df6058bb395e985833189) of `/etc/skel/.profile` and you can see that the last line reads `PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`.

In short, for "new" user accounts, you don't have to do anything. For "old" user accounts, you can append `$HOME/.local/bin` to `PATH` in `/etc/environment`, which would also affect the "new" user accounts too but no harm is done.