# Can't use sniffer (Python auto-testing tool)

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, pip

I'm running python3 on Xubuntu 16.04.

I installed sniffer (Python auto-testing tool) with

```
$ pip3 install sniffer
```

I also installed pyinotify with

```
$ pip3 install pyinotify
```

When I try to run

```
$ sniffer
```

I get

```
sniffer: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `$PATH` does not include `$HOME/.local/bin`. Use your favorite text editor to open `~/.profile` and append the following to it:

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then, run this in the terminal:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Incidentally, as I have explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/801053/15003), if you had created your user account recently, your `$PATH` would have included `$HOME/.local/bin` by default.

Comment: Nice, please consider accepting the answer so that people who have a similar problem would know this answer works. :)

Comment: I just had to wait 2 minutes to accept it. We were too fast for the site ;-).